# Redirect old domain to new domain. Set custom redirect for shorter URL

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I am using `RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.longerdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]` to redirect a shorter domain and all it's pages to a longer domain. It is working great, but now I am needing to add a condition or an additional rule that allows for http://short.com/donate to redirect to http://longerdomain.com/donation-form. I have tried this `Redirect 301 /donate http://www.longerdomain.com/donation-form` after the RewriteRule, but with no success. How would I achieve this? Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of doing it, using `mod_rewrite`,

```
RewriteRule ^/donate$ http://longerdomain.com/donation-form [R=301,L]
```

and place it before your general

```
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.longerdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

rule, as that rule will redirect anything given to it.

Comment: Note that if this is in `.htaccess` (as indicated by the question tag) then you'll need to remove the slash prefix from the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` _pattern_. ie. should be `^donate$`, not `^/donate$`